# Does a dashed line mean "when energized"?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, relay, coil

I'm having a hard time understanding this circuit diagram:
[image]

I'm interested in the following component sates, and how they affect power distribution:

**the breakers:**
[image]

**the buses:**
[image]

**the AVIO MSTR switch:** 
[image]

I'm not well-versed in schematics, but I'm under the impression, that the dotted vertical line means "when energized"?
[image]

Does that mean the `Avionic Buses` cannot be powered unless the `MASTER CB` is popped?

This is my best guess on deciding whether the avionic buses receive power:
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm not well-versed in schematics, but I'm under the impression, that the dotted vertical line means "when energized"?

Dashed line means that there is a mechanical connection. Used in switches and relays in your diagrams.

In effect it means, that when the essential bus 1 relay is energized (current flows from X1 to X2) relay pulls the switches A and B into the down-position (marked with triangle).

So, when the relay is not energized, you have connection between A2 and A3, and B2 and B3. When relay is energized, there is connection between A2 and A1, and B2 and B1.

It is important to note that unless otherwise told in the drawing, they are drawn in **not energized / off state**.

And for the switch S70003 (Avionic Master) dashed line just indicates that it is a switch.

> Does that mean the Avionic Buses cannot be powered unless the MASTER CB is popped?

According to the diagram you provided, avionic bus is powered whenever essential bus 1 relay and shed bus 1 relay **are not** energized. So if you pull the master cb, you are powering avionic bus and render avionic master switch useless.

Comment: excellent answer (your first answer I believe). Thumbs up and +1

Comment: I'm an engineer and this is correct. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

*Figure 1. Cropped version of OP's schematic to improve legibility.*

- Standard practice is to draw switches and relays in their un-operated state. Push-buttons, if normally open type, will show the contacts open. Relays will show their contacts in the de-energised state.
- In Figure 1 we can see that B2 is connected to B3 when de-energised and connected to B1 when energised.
- The dotted line shows that all the contacts driven by the associated coil.

> When is the coil energized?

- Without understanding anything else about the application we can deduce the polarity of the supply on account of the diodes incorporated in the relays (1). These are "snubber" diodes and give a path for current to flow when the relay coil is switched off.
- When the relay coil is energised the diodes must be reverse biased - otherwise they would present a short-circuit to ground - so that means that
  the right-hand side is + and the left -.
- That in turn means that positive supply or battery +, or whatever it is, is connected to (2) and negative to (3).

> When both X2 and X1 receive current?

You haven't got your terminology right here. The coil will be energised when current *flows through* the coil. This will happen when X1 is connected to + and X2 is connected to -. For this to happen to K70013 CB70009 must be closed and AVIO MSTR I switched OFF.

> Does that mean the Avionic Buses cannot be powered unless the MASTER CB is popped?

The master CB must be closed (un-popped?) for the relays to be energised.

Answer (score 2):

The dashed line in a multi-pole switch or relay means that the contacts the dashed line join all move together when the relay is operated or the switch is moved.

In the drawing of the single relay, both moving contacts will move down (connecting B1 to B2, and A1 to A2) when the relay coil is energised.

Comment: When is the relay coil energized?  When both `X2` and `X1` receive current?

Comment: "Energised" = when the appropriate voltage is applied across the coil (X1 and X2)